# Property [roles] does not exist on this collection instance after relations defined

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I'm trying to eager load all the roles that belong to a permission. `$permissions = \App\Permission::with('roles')->get();`

When I try and `return $permissions->roles;` I'm getting this error even though I've already set the appropriate relations:

> Property [roles] does not exist on this collection

**Permissions Model Relation**

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

When I simply `return $permissions;` I get the appropriate output:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"edit_post",
      "label":"Edit Posts",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "roles":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"admin",
            "label":"Admin",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null,
            "pivot":{  
               "permission_id":1,
               "role_id":1
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "name":"delete_post",
      "label":"Delete Posts",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "roles":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"admin",
            "label":" Admin",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null,
            "pivot":{  
               "permission_id":2,
               "role_id":1
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the permissions roles.

```
foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
    return $permission->roles;
}
```

Comment: you should make this question as answered

Comment: I would if I could accept my question right away, but I got for 2 days